# Asterisk получить номер после звёздочки

Tags: asterisk, voip

Привет всем!

Я хочу чтобы при звонке на внешний номер была возможность переадресовать сразу на внутренний. Например если звонящий набрал `+71234567890*111` то после дозвона на `+71234567890` его переадресовали на внутренний `111` номер. Того же самого можно достичь позвонив на `+71234567890` и по приглашению автоответчика набрать `111`, но это несколько дольше. Проблема в том что ни в одном из полей переменной `${CALLERID}` `("name", "num", "all", "ANI", "DNID", "RDNIS")` я не вижу цифр после звёздочки. Думаю что моб.оператор не передаёт никуда `111`, а вы что скажете?

Comment: Немного не понял.  +71234567890 - это номер астериска? Или это некий номер, на который Вы с астериска звоните?

Comment: +71234567890 -- это номер астериска, НА который я звоню.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы набрали будет в переменной `${EXTEN}` а не в `${CALLERID}`
Номер и "звездочка" на который вы набрали в данный момент будет префиксом.
для обрезки префикса можно использовать подобные операции:

```
${123456789:1} = 23456789
${123456789:-4} = 6789
${123456789:0:3} = 123
${123456789:2:3} = 345
${123456789:-4:3} = 678 

${+71234567890*111:13} = 111
```

Это конечно если номер приходит в таком формате на Астер.

Comment: Номер не приходит в таком формате, к сожалению.

Answer (score 0):

Да, точно, перепутал переменную. Вы совершенно правы.

В dialplan добавил: `exten => _+[0-9].,n,Verbose(${EXTEN})`

Звоню с мобильного на gsm модем астериска +71234567890. Набираю +71234567890*111, а в консоли вижу:

```
-- Executing [+71234567890@from-MEGAFON:2] Verbose("Dongle/MEGAFON-0100000000", "+71234567890") in new stack
```

Без, части после звёздочки. Но даже когда я набираю номер 81234567890, он переписывается видимо астером и приходит с +7 в начале вместо 8. Видимо не получится чтоб звонящий сразу передавал номер внутреннего абонента?